# JSDoc - Document Object of type

Tags: javascript, parameters, documentation, jsdoc

In JSDoc, how does one document an Object of certain defined type?

For example, if I have a function which receives a `HTMLImageElement` object, how should I document it in the parameters?

Would it be like just like this `@param {HTMLImageElement} - An image` or `@param {Object<HTMLImageElement>}` ?

Comment: You already had answered your question    
`@param {HTMLImageElement} - An image` this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option you mentioned is correct:

```
@param {HTMLImageElement} An image
```

All class/object types can be used as a type in the type parameter. You don't need to do anything fancy with them.

And since all class instances are objects, you know it is also an object.